# Vue3 with Jest stub functionality does not stub

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

Component:

```
<template>
  <div id="fileviewer" class="min-h-full">
    <section class="gap-4 mt-4">
      <div class="bg-medium-50 w-1/3 p-4">
        <FileUpload ></FileUpload>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-medium-50 w-2/3 p-4">
        <FileViewer></FileViewer>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FileUpload from "@/components/FileUpload";
import FileViewer from "@/components/FileViewer";

export default {
  name: "FileManager",
  components: { FileUpload, FileViewer },
};
</script>
```

Test:

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import FileManager from '@/views/FileManager';

describe('FileManager.vue', () =>{

  it('should mount', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(FileManager, {
      global: {
        stubs: {
          FileUpload: true,
          FileViewer: true
        }
      }
    })

    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined()
  })

})
```

Does not work for me as per the [docs](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/a-crash-course.html#adding-a-new-todo). No special installations. Instead, The framework wants to do the 'import' statements for the child components and then fails because I do not want to mock out 'fetch' for this one component. Any Ideas?

```
"vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.9"
"@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.6"
"vue": "^3.0.0",
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I**. If you want to stub all child components automatically you just can use `shallowMount` instead of `mount`.

**II**. If you want so use `mount` anyway try to fix your stubs like that:

```
global: {
  stubs: {
    FileUpload: {
      template: '<div class="file-upload-or-any-class-you-want">You can put there anything you want</div>'
    },
    FileViewer: {
      template: '<div class="file-viewer-or-any-class-you-want">You can put there anything you want</div>'
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can define your stubs before tests as I always do. For example:

```
const FileUploadStub = {
  template: '<div class="file-upload-or-any-class-you-want">You can put there anything you want</div>'
}

const FileViewerStub: {
  template: '<div class="file-viewer-or-any-class-you-want">You can put there anything you want</div>'
}
```

And then use stubs in `mount` or `shallowMount`:

```
global: {
  stubs: {
    FileUpload: FileUploadStub,
    FileViewer: FileViewerStub
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem for me was that although I used shallowMount, the Framework would still mount the imports in the child components (e. g. the test would fail because it tried to import firebase although I used shallowMount.